# How can I make this chainsaw teeth effect in an animated mesh?

Tags: animation, rigging, bezier-curves

Blender version 3.6

I have this model of a chainsword. I'm using a bezier curve to help with animating its teeth.

[image: Chainsaw teeth effect]

If I move the bones at all to animate it, though, the effect completely breaks.

[image: Chainsaw teeth effect breaking]

Any way to solve this, or a way to get the same looping effect without using a curve and thus avoiding the issue?

Comment: Parenting the curve to the sword so that it moves with it? Or to the bone? Just saw you are using a bone... why in this case? Is this part of a character rig?

Comment: i would recommend providing your blend file so we can check it out

Answer (score 0):

since you didn't provide a blend file, here a quick way how you can do it:

1. create a curve (cyclic) and an object
2. give the object an array modifier (fit curve) and a curve modifier

[image]

3. parent both to an empty
4. animate the objects x-position (depending on your scenario this might be another axis)

result:

[image]